# Java class not reading fx:id from FXML file

Tags: java, javafx, fxml

I'm making a JavaFX application but for some reason, my controller class isn't recognizing the FX ids in my FXML file.

Here is my FXML code:

```
//fxml code....
<AnchorPane id="Meta Data GUI" maxHeight="-1.0" maxWidth="-1.0" minHeight="-1.0" minWidth="-1.0" prefHeight="-1.0" prefWidth="-1.0" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/2.2" fx:controller="com.cisco.gaxl.metadatagui.windows.controllers.MainWindowController">
   //components....
   <Button fx:id="addTableButton" onAction="#testMethod" contentDisplay="CENTER" mnemonicParsing="false" prefWidth="-1.0" text="Add Table" textAlignment="CENTER" VBox.vgrow="NEVER">
   //more components...
</AnchorPane>
```

And here is my Java code

```
import javafx.fxml.FXML
//more imports....
public class MainWindowController {
     //fields....
     @FXML private static addTableButton;

     @FXML void initialize() {
         //code...
         assert addTableButton != null : "fx:id=\"addTableButton\" was not injected: check your FXML file 'metadataEditor.fxml'.";
         //code....
         addTableButton.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
             //code...
         }
     }

     @FXML private void testMethod() { System.out.println("Something"); }

}
```

I get a nullpointer exception at the `addTableButton.setOnAction` declaration, whcih is weird because it should've been  caught by my assert statement. I have verified that my class is correctly defined as the controller class and that all other parts of my FXML are correct.

Now if I comment out the `setOnAction` declaration (as well as all my other JavaFX components) the GUI will output as normal but just without any actions. However, clicking the addTableButton will still execute `testMethod` as I defined it in my FXML file, so it seems like everything but the fx:id's are working.

Does anyone have an idea as to what's going on here? I'm sure I'm doing something very silly but any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Javafx doesn't seem to accept static variables, also you didn't declare a type.  Here's what you would need:

> ```
> @FXML
> private Button addTableButton;
> ```